# What is the answer to "Message to go in the Times (5)"?

Tags: cryptic-clues

The clue is

> Message to go in the Times (5)

What is the answer? Please included explanations of wordplay/indicators in your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> **TWEET** = message (on Twitter). The wordplay is **WEE**, "to go" (to the lavatory) in **T** + **T**, "times" (*t* denotes time in physics ).
>
>  This clue is from [yesterday's Guardian cryptic by Puck](http://www.fifteensquared.net/2018/11/20/guardian-cryptic-27671-by-puck/). The site I linked to provides detailed solutions for cryptic crosswords in the Guardian, Financial Times and the Independent.

Comment: Is there a reason why the T of times is capitalised

Comment: Sure: the surface reading. The Times is an English newspaper and the casual reading of the clue should be about a message that's to be published in the Times. (I think it's okay to have a capitalised word clue the uncapitalised one, but not the other way round. Think of all the Sues, Bills, Franks and Robs.)

Answer (score -4):

The answer is:

> "items".
>
>  This is a simple anagram of "times".

Comment: I'd agree except there aren't any indicators for it to be an anagram. Normally with cryptic clues they would include a word that would indicate that you should anagram it.

Comment: Plus, I don't think 'items' fits the def of 'Message'